# PHP & XML - Count descendant of a node

Tags: php, xml

I'm working on the Amazon partners API to get some informations about product. They had a XML element to get catégories of a product which look like that :

```
<BrowseNodes>
<BrowseNode>
    <BrowseNodeId>464711031</BrowseNodeId>
        <Name>Soutiens-gorge de tous les jours</Name>
        <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
               <BrowseNodeId>464710031</BrowseNodeId>
               <Name>Soutiens-gorge</Name>
               <Ancestors>
                    <BrowseNode>
                        <BrowseNodeId>464709031</BrowseNodeId>
                        <Name>Lingerie</Name>
                        <Ancestors>
                            <BrowseNode>
                            <BrowseNodeId>436559031</BrowseNodeId>
                            <Name>Femme</Name>
                            <Ancestors>
                                <BrowseNode>
                                <BrowseNodeId>340856031</BrowseNodeId>
                                <Name>Catégories</Name>
                                <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
                                <Ancestors>
                                    <BrowseNode>
                                    ...
```

And so on. Sometime there is only three descendant sometimes more...

So my question is, how could i count how much descendant is there without guessing with a for loop ?

And my second question is, how could I put the next code into a for loop ? I don't see it...

```
$cL = $item->BrowseNodes->BrowseNode;
if(isset($cL)){
    $catTree[] = (string)$cL->Name;
    $cL0 = $cL->Ancestors->BrowseNode;

    if(isset($cL0)){
    $catTree[] = (string)$cL0->Name;    
    $cL1 = $cL0->Ancestors->BrowseNode;

    if(isset($cL1)){
        $catTree[] = (string)$cL1->Name;
        $cL2 = $cL1->Ancestors->BrowseNode; 

        if(isset($cL2)){
                    $catTree[] = (string)$cL2->Name;
            $cL3 = $cL2->Ancestors->BrowseNode;

                        if(isset($cL3)){                    
                            $catTree[] = (string)$cL3->Name;    
                            ...
```

and it continues also...

Actually this code is working but I'm sure it could be a lot more simple... Just don't know how.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: hmm..I see recursion here :)

Comment: You can use XPath and an axis such as `descendant-or-self`: `//Name[.='Catégories'][1]` in XPath will return the first occurrence of the `Name` element containing the `Catégories` string. From there you can move along the tree relatively to that node and get anything you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count elements you don't need use loops. Try this.

```
$xml = "<BrowseNodes>
            <BrowseNode>
               <BrowseNodeId>464710031</BrowseNodeId>
               <Name>Soutiens-gorge</Name>
            </BrowseNode>
            <BrowseNode>
               <BrowseNodeId>464710033</BrowseNodeId>
               <Name>Soutiens-gorge333</Name>
            </BrowseNode>
        </BrowseNodes>";

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$xml->xpath("/BrowseNode");
echo "count: ".$xml->count();
```

But if you want use loop it will not work in this case. you need recursion as mentioned  @1nflktd

Comment: I didn't try yet but i think it will not work because your structure is different from the one i posted. The next 'BrowseNode' is in the 'Ancestors' part of the previous 'BrowseNode' and is not a brother nor direct children of 'BrowseNodeS'. That's all my problem. But I'll try and my apologies if it's working even with a different structure.

Comment: It's a concept. You didn't try the code because there is no valid XML. but XPATH will work on original xml

Answer (score 2):

Using XPath:

```
$document = new DOMDocument(); 
$document->load( "your-file.xml" ); 
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$count = $xpath->evaluate("count(/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode)");
```

You can also use XPath to select all nodes and extract the values you need.